# Trouble creating a navigation bar

Tags: css, menu, navigation

I'm trying to create little navigation bar that will stay on certain position of the page even the the user is scrolling through it. I'm a total noob so I started out using the css for a navigation button from the template that i'm using. But for the life of me I cannot figure out how to add two more buttons. I'm sorry if this is a supernoob question but I could really use the help. Thanks guys!

The website is www.muzedimage.com
this is what I have in mind: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bv4rh.jpg

The HTML segment for the button is:

```
<div class="downArrow"> 
   <div class="row">
      <div class="large-1 small-2 column push-11"> 
         <a href="#whatwedo" class="scroll down"><i class="icon-chevron-down"></i></a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The CSS Style Sheet:

```
section.banner {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
section.banner .downArrow {
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    text-align: center;
}
section.banner .downArrow a.down {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 60px;
    background: #cb7039;
    text-align: center;
}
section.banner .downArrow a.down i {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.688em;
  line-height: 60px;
  -webkit-transition: line-height 0.1s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: line-height 0.1s ease-in;
  -o-transition: line-height 0.1s ease-in;
  transition: line-height 0.1s ease-in;
}
section.banner .downArrow a.down:hover i {
  line-height: 80px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a little [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/F9Hrh/1/) that can give you a start.

Spend your time playing with the CSS.
And add/style as many buttons as you want.

HTML

```
<div class='holder'>
    <div class='button1'>X</div>
    <div class='button1'>Y</div>
    <div class='button1'>W</div>
    <div class='button1'>Z</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I didnt have this in mind but it works. One question is that how do I snap it to the bottom of the page instead of the top? and to the right instead of the left?

Comment: Google CSS fixed positioning and you will learn about position: fixed, right: 0px, bottom: 0px.